# How to scroll only the widgets(Content) but not the background in android

Tags: android, scrollview

I defined ScrollView and I put inside some buttons. I have two problems:

1. If I have a little bit buttons then the background is too small
   and does not cover whole screen.
2. I want to just move buttons but not the the background when I
   scroll.

Thank you

Comment: Post your layout file so we can see the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Put the scrollview inside a linear layout or a framelayout and add the background to the outer layouts. So when only the items in your scroll view will move.

Also try adding background directly to the scrollview and not to its child elements, that might work without needing to add a extra out layout like I mentioned above.

Comment: it dont work its write "You must supply a layout_width attribute"

Comment: You must specify a layout_width and layout_height attribute for every view.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, what is the scrollview's layout_width and layout_height values? I'm guessing it's wrap_content. Try changing it to match_parent or fill_parent.

For your second question, blessenm's reply works for me.